# IFormFile not load type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 3.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When using IFormFile I am getting this error at running time:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

I have tried adding packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" Version="2.2.0" />
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;
IFormFile f = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, "test", "test.pdf");
```

Documentation exists for FormFile [Aspnetcore 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.formfile?view=aspnetcore-3.0). However when checking my sdk, instead of using 3.0. It is only available in .net core 2.2. I have both versions 2.2 and 3.0 installed

## region Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

```
// C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll
#endregion

using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal
{
    public class FormFile : IFormFile
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updated your references to all be `3.0.0`? Having `http` at `2.2.2` and `http.features` at `3.0.0` may be the problem

Comment: thank you for your comment, I cannot find Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http version 3.0.0, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/

Comment: This might be a X-Y problem. Just curious:  why do you create a `IFormFile` instance manually by `new FormFile` ?

Comment: Im calling a api that returns a file and I have to send it again to another api that receives IFormFile

Comment: @Exec21 If that's the case, there's no need to invoke the `FormFile`. Just sent a File via `HttpClient`.

Comment: @itminus I need to send multiple files

Comment: @Exec21 It makes no differences: Using Multipart  format will make it.

Comment: @itminus i've tried sending them but the headers which are inside of the IFormFile made the trick Headers = new HeaderDictionary()
                    {
                            
                    },
                    ContentDisposition = "Attachment",
                    ContentType = "application/pdf"

Comment: @Exec21 Could you please elaborate on this a little more? Is there any problem when using multipart format?

Comment: @itminus sure, I tried setting the headers of the ByteArrayContent straightaway there, but they are not working well, if I add them in the IFormFile, everything works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202533/discussion-between-itminus-and-exec21).

Comment: @itminus helped me solve my problem.  In a .Net Standard 2.1 library I only have issues when I try and instantiate an IFormFile.  If I pass this same NetStandard2.1 library an IForm file everything works fine.  I tried adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to the library project but that package is not compatible with NetStandard 2.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was facing the same error and could not find anything directly related to this error and after two days battling with this issue finally, I have found the solution.

The problem occurs when you try to instantiate FormFile or FormFileCollection class. If the project does not have a framework reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, it will throw the above error.

Solution:

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** framework reference needs to be added manually whichever project is instantiating FormFile or FormFileCollection class.

```
 <ItemGroup>
     <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference

Answer (score 2):

I am under .NET 5 and the solution of @RL89 conceptionally works but in practice it changed.

You need to change to first line in your *.csproj file to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Notice that it is Microsoft.NET.Sdk **.Web**

You solution will not compile unless you have a main method. I simply created a fake Program.cs like this

```
namespace MyClassProjThatTurnedIntoWebProject
{
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("This project is not meant to be run. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67097605/828184");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I could do fun stuff like creating a new FormFile() like this:

```
FormFile file;
string path = "/file/path.json";
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
    file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name));
}
```