# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.0.3.0...'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm currently upgrading my ASP.NET core project to netcoreapp3.0.

I've followed the guide here:

[Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

I've got my target Sdk and framework as the following:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="12.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="IronPdf" Version="2019.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="3.7.4">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="4.2.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="MiniProfiler.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="4.2.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="PnP.Core" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="PnP.Core.Auth" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.EJ2.AspNet.Core" Version="18.2.0.48" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Licensing" Version="18.2.0.48" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" Version="4.3.1" />
</ItemGroup>

....
```

As detailed in the guide above, I haven't explicitly declared a reference to:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
```

Everything builds OK, however, when I run the program I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.0.3.0
```

I've followed similar questions here

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445639/unable-to-upload-file-after-moving-from-netcore-2-2-to-3-1)

and here

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904234/iformfile-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-internal-formfile-from-assemb)

however I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Maybe not helpful but why are you upgrading to 3.0? It is already out of support (see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.0). Why not 3.1 or 6.0 (the currently supported LTS releases).

Comment: @SBFrancies, thanks for your comment. I've tried going up to 6.0 and have the same issue, so rolled back to when I first got the issue to try and fix here.